# Finding FPS and Bitrate of rtsp stream using VLCJ

Tags: java, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

I'm using vlcj to create a media player.

I can play rtsp streams successfully. 
But I want to display streams' fps and bitrate as the video is being played.

Since values may be variable, I need to update the values as the stream is being played. So I need data from the player itself.

But:

```
List<TrackInfo> videoTrackInfo = mediaPlayer.getTrackInfo(TrackType.VIDEO);
```

returns null in my case.

Also:

```
mediaPlayer.getRate();
mediaPlayer.getFps();
```

returns 0.0 (float) and 1.0 (float). Which are not correct of course.

In VLC itself, with a stream with vbr, you can see the bitrate of that moment. I hope it is possible to get those values from vlcj as well.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With something like an RTSP stream the media you are playing is actually some sort of "playlist".

A playlist doesn't have a bit-rate or an FPS and so on.

When you play a playlist what actually happens is that VLC, or its plugins, parses your playlist URL and generates "sub-items" for the actual media itself. Typically the first such sub-item will be the media stream that you want, and that vlcj will play by default.

So, use the media player API methods that work with sub-items.

For example there is `mediaPlayer.getSubItemTrackInfo()`, Javadoc at http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.10.1/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/MediaPlayer.html#getSubItemTrackInfo-uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.TrackType...-

You will need to listen for media player events to know when sub-items have been created and make sure not to invoke the API before that happens.

Comment: Thanks for reply. What are these "the media player API methods that work with sub-items" ? Are those methods of MediaListPlayer (If so I couldn't find any related methods of it)? Also  I tried "subItemPlayed" listener, but it is not called during the stream is being played. I'm sorry that I couldn't figure out/understand information you provided.

Comment: (During the mediaPlayer is playing the rtsp stream) When I call mediaPlayer.getSubItemTrackInfo().toString() I get [] and when I call mediaPlayer.getSubItemTrackInfo().size() I get 0. This is not what we expected I guess. Is there an exception to your "playing like some sort of playlist" state? Also, If there was subItems being created/played, wouldn't subıtemPlayed listener be called (as I mentioned in my previous comment, it is not called during playing?

Comment: subItemPlayed, endOfSubItems, mediaSubItemTreeAdded, mediaSubItemAdded, elementaryStreamAdded... non of these are being called even tough playing and mediaStateChanged (with 5) listeners gets called.

Comment: I forgot to mention your username in my previous comments. Plus, I added screenshot of the simple info i need to achieve. When I play the same stream in VLC, it shows the FPS value. Isn't there an easy way to at least get that ? @caprica

Comment: I don't know. Every RTSP stream I've played looks like a playlist. As for an "easy way", you get what the LibVLC API provides. That is often a sub-set of what VLC itself provides.

Comment: What about the elementaryStreamAdded event, or elementaryStreamSelected, do those fire and can you read the track info after you receive those events?